# How to use aggregation famework of mongodb 2.2 with pre-aggregated report/collection

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have Pre-Aggregated collection like following way:

```
DAILY_ANALYTIC.update(
{
  "_id": id_daily,
  "metadata": {"date": d,},
},
{
  "$inc": {
      "call_daily": 1,
      "call_hourly.%d" % (hour,): 1,
      "call_minute.%d.%d" % (hour, minute,): 1,                
    }
}, upsert=True)
```

I want to do grouping on call_hourly data & for that I tried following way but not wotking

```
[
    {'$match': query_var},
    {'$group': {
        '_id': {'$substr': ['$_id', 0, 8]},            
        'call_per_hour': {'$addToSet' : '$call_hourly'},            
        }
    },
    {'$project': {            
        'call_per_hour': 1,            
        }
    },        
    {'$sort': {
        '_id': -1,            
        }
    }
]
```

Any idea how to get result like

```
data['result'] = {'_id': '20121102', 'call_per_hour':[{u'3': 5, u'12': 6}]}
```

or

```
data['result'] = {'_id': '20121102', 'call_per_hour':[{u'0': 5, u'1': 6, u'2': 4,....,u'23': 2}]}
```

Comment: First, you need to use $project to create the documents you want to "$group" - that's where operators like $substr are used to construct new fields, for example.  Second - it appears that you want to group by day not by hour and get average calls per hour for that day, looking at the output you want?  Can you give a sample document from your collection and confirm the grouping/type of output you want?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing this, you already have all the hourly call counts available in your document.

Since you are incrementing fields in your date document for each call, if you just do:

```
db.daily_analytic.find({}, {"metadata.date":1, _id:0, call_hourly:1})
```

or something similar.

If you feel that you need to aggregate and do a "`$group` by" (even though your code is already pre-grouping things in the original document) please provide several sample documents out of your collection (via mongo shell you can just do `db.daily_analytic.find().limit(2).pretty()` and paste the output into your question) and then it will be easier to see where there are aggregation possibilities for values you don't have precomputed.